# Convert String to ArrayType in column and explode

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe where a column is in string type whereas the string is a 2D array/list which needs to be exploded into rows. However, since it is not a Struct/Array Type it's not possible to use `explode` directly.

This can be seen in the example below:

```
a = [('Bob', 562,"Food", "[[29,June,2018],[12,May,2018]]"), ('Bob',880,"Food","[[01,June,2018]]"), ('Bob',380,'Household',"[[16,June,2018]]")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(a, ["Person", "Amount","Budget", "Date"])

df.printSchema()
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- Person: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Amount: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Budget: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Date: string (nullable = true)
```

The output I am looking for is seen below. I need to be able to convert the String to a Struct/Array so that I can explode:

```
+------+------+---------+---+-----+-----+
|Person|Amount|Budget   |Day|Month|Year |
+------+------+---------+---+-----+-----+
|Bob   |562   |Food     |29 |June |2018 |
|Bob   |562   |Food     |12 |May  |2018 |
|Bob   |880   |Food     |01 |June |2018 |
|Bob   |380   |Household|16 |June |2018 |
+------+------+---------+---+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with removing the outer `[[` and `]]` and splitting the string on all `],[`.
After splitting the data will be in an array, making it possible to use the `explode` function. After that, what is left is simply to format the data into the desired output using another `split` and `getItem`.

It can be done as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('date_arr', F.split(F.regexp_replace('Date', '\[\[|\]\]', ''), ','))\
  .withColumn('date_arr', F.explode('date_arr'))\
  .withColumn('date_arr', F.split('date_arr', ','))\
  .select('Person',
          'Amount',
          'Budget',
          'date_arr'.getItem(0).alias('Day'),
          'date_arr'.getItem(0).alias('Month'),
          'date_arr'.getItem(0).alias('Year'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string in the same format you showed us, then you need to do perform the tasks :

1. Split the columns in as many array you have with `explode`
2. Remove the [ and ]
3. Split the date by `,` comma
4. assign each member of the new array to its column.

If I write you the code :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.select("Person",
          "Amount",
          "Budget",
          F.explode(F.split("Date", '],')).alias("date_array")
         ).select("Person",
                  "Amount",
                  "Budget",
                  F.split(F.translate(F.translate("date_array", '[', ''), ']', ''), ',').alias("date_array")
                 ).select("Person",
                          "Amount",
                          "Budget",
                          F.col("date_array").getItem(0).alias("Day"),
                          F.col("date_array").getItem(1).alias("Month"),
                          F.col("date_array").getItem(2).alias("Year"),
                         ).show()

+------+------+---------+---+-----+----+
|Person|Amount|   Budget|Day|Month|Year|
+------+------+---------+---+-----+----+
|   Bob|   562|     Food| 29| June|2018|
|   Bob|   562|     Food| 12|  May|2018|
|   Bob|   880|     Food| 01| June|2018|
|   Bob|   380|Household| 16| June|2018|
+------+------+---------+---+-----+----+
```